# SELECT calculando a média de nota em MySQL

Tags: mysql

Em um sistema de treinamentos tenho duas tabelas:

TABELA **nota_locais**:

```
id
id_local
nota
```

TABELA **locais**:

```
id
nome
```

A tabela **nota_locais** armazena as notas que cada usuário da para o local onde ocorreu o treinamento. Quando vou listar todos os locais de treinamentos, dou um select na tabela **locais**, mas queria além de listar o local, dizer qual a média de nota que esse local tem, ou seja, dar um select também na tabela **nota_locais** e já calculando a média, como fazer?

Comment: `SELECT l.nome, SUM(n.nota) / COUNT(n.nota) FROM locais as l INNER JOIN nota_locais as n ON n.id_local = locais.id` funciona? Se sim posto uma resposta explicando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute a query abaixo

```
select l.id, l.nome, AVG(nl.nota)
from nota_locais nl
inner join locais l  on  l.id = nl.id_local
group by l.id, l.nome
```

Comment: Valeu, só não dei a sua como certa pq responderam antes.

Comment: a resposta anterior não responde a sua pergunta, pois não está utilizando o group by

Comment: Verdade, testei e realmente não agrupou

Answer (score 1):

Faça a seguinte operação de junção das chaves e aplicando as funções AVG e GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
   nome,
   AVG(nota) AS 'media'
FROM locais L
INNER JOIN notas_locais NL ON
L.id = NL.id_local
GROUP BY 
   id,
   nome
```